# How to mix RTK Query apiSlice reducers with regular RTK reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm migrating some of our old Redux actions over from our original bespoke app to RTK Query and I've run into an issue which is likely just my lack of understanding of RTK Query.

I have an `apiSlice` as follows

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { AUTH_SERVER, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI } from 'app/config'

const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'auth',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `https://${AUTH_SERVER}`
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    tokenFetch: builder.query({
      query: ({ code, code_verifier }) => ({
        url: '/oauth/token',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          code_verifier,
          code,
          redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI
        }
      })
    }),
    tokenRefresh: builder.query({
      query: ({ refresh_token }) => ({
        url: '/oauth/token',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          grant_type: 'refresh_token',
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          refresh_token
        }
      })
    })
  })
})

export const { useTokenFetchQuery, useTokenRefreshQuery } = api

export default api
```

I have three issues I can't currently figure out:

1. I want to persist the user's auth tokens in the brower, (using redux-persist middleware in the original app - not sure how to integrate that here)
2. I need the results of `tokenRefresh` to overwite the original `tokenFetch` api call, (currently they are stored independently) and
3. I need to handle a `tokenInvalidate` action with a reducer that simply resets the auth state. (I can't see how I'd inject other reducers into this apiSlice)

How do I ensure that `tokenFetch` and `tokenRefresh` both push data to the same part of the redux state, and how do I inject a reducer in addition to the api calls to erase that state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RTK docs have an example of [saving an auth token to the side with extraReducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers).

I think that shows most of what you want - saving the token to the side in an extra slice that you can manipulate at will, by using the `fulfilled` action of your endpoint in `extraReducers`.

Also, it shows how to use that token in `prepareHeaders` of your `baseQuery`.

In addition to that, you might want to [wrap your baseQuery for automatic re-authentication](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery).

Comment: @Abhi there is a high question that you have a completely different problem with similar symptoms. ask your own question and provide enough code & context